# Looking for a package able to do this highlighting+labeling

Tags: highlighting

I am looking for a way to do the following highlighting : see the word "be".

---

[image: example annotation]

---

I did some googling to find an answer but I wasn't lucy!

I also tried other ways such as converting the HTML output to TeX with pandoc but that was also a dead end.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use  a `\colorbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like suggested by projetmbc you could use `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox\strangehighlight
  {
     fontupper=\sffamily
    ,size=small
    ,colback=gray!50
    ,nobeforeafter
    ,tcbox raise base
    ,frame empty
  }

\begin{document}
This killing of a respected cleric will \strangehighlight{be v} causing us
trouble for years to come.
\end{document}
```

[image]